# how to define a constant String in spring framework and use in JSP?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want to check if a specific item is selected in a drop-down menu. Suppose I have something like this in my JSP:

```
<sf:select path="xItem" >
    <sf:option value="val1" />
    <sf:option value="val2" />
</sf:select>
```

and in my corresponding java bean, I want to check it as

```
if (xItem.equals("val1")) xItem = doSomething();
```

but, if I define "val1" as a constant, i.e., `final static String mytext="val1"`, and change my jsp file as `<sf:option value="${MyClass.mytext}" />`, Spring will complain that `mytext` is not a property of MyClass.
Is there anyway to define this text as a constant and refer to it in JSP and the corresponding Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${MyClass.mytext}` expression applies to beans and properties, specifically it means that the server is expecting to find a bean saved in the current context as `MyClass` and on that bean to call a getter called `getMyText` (it's a [`jspContext.FindAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)) which isn't the case here since you have a static member on a class.

Here are some workarounds off the top of my head:

- use a scriptlet and refer to the static member (if you can live with having scriptlets inside your JSPs);
- save the value in your controller under some key inside your [model](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) and refer it in your JSP by that key;
- define a custom tag that given a class name and static member invokes it and places it under some key in page scope and you can use if from there (see an example in this article: [Scriptless JSP Pages: The Constant Constants Consternation](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/Journal200601.jsp#a3));
- define an EL function that returns the value of the constant (see an example in the same article [Scriptless JSP Pages: The Constant Constants Consternation](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/Journal200601.jsp#a3), scroll to the end of it).

I would personally go with defining an EL function if you refer to constants often in your JSPs or set it under some model key in the controller if it's a one time only use.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And please excuse my ignorance. Could you tell me how do you mean to "save the value under some key inside the controller"?

Comment: Sorry, poor choice of words. I meant that in your controller to place the value inside a key in the model. I have updated my answer. What you place in the model is added by Spring as attributes on the request and is accessible in the view. In Spring 3, if you are using that version, the model can even be a java.util.Map implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It will not allow as it require getter setters for property and for final static variable you can't have setters so in that case you have to remove final static.